# How make a picture slideshow

Tags: beamer, sectioning, header-footer

I would like to use beamer class as backbone for my presentation. However, I encountered a problem. My wish is to put pictures on it and for LaTeX to decide their placement and divide them on frames (Not necessarily one picture per frame).

Only text that should be visible is section and subsection headers describing what is the content of pictures. Is there an easy and elegant way to do it without needing to specify pictures frame by frame.

For example I put a collection of pictures somewhere and automatically they are divided across frames with common header without manual parsing each frame.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) sounds (at least related) to [Automatic beamer presentation with one slide generated for each image in a directory?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/94941)